does css have an ancestor selector?
<style>
path[fill] {
    fill: gray;
    transition: fill 0.3s;
}

path[fill] has-parent('div'):hover {
    fill: red;
}
</style>


is tis possible somehow? I'm trying to set a :hover effect the svg parent's element.

why not div:hover path[div]?

Do you know what ancestor means?

No, sorry. never heard before today.
